# How do I get other representations of the Gamma function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, special-functions

In my studymaterial I see  different definitions of the Gamma function
In *Mathematica* it is for example:

```
Gamma[z] == 1/z Product[(1 + 1/k)^z/(1 + z/k),
                        {k, 1, Infinity}]/; Not[Element[-z, Integers]\[And] -z >= 0]
```

`( z={0,1,2,..}`
Is there an easy way to get (derive) some other forms of the Gamma function here defined ?
Hoping that one of the forms looks the same as in my studymaterial.

Example: $Pi(s) = \prod _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{n^{1-s}
   (n+1)^s}{n+s}$

Comment: See https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/ to this end.

Comment: @user64494 , thanks i will look there if i can derive a wanted form?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is `MathematicalFunctionData` which can be exploited to get various representations of the Euler `Gamma` function. As a starting point one can evaluate e.g.

```
MathematicalFunctionData["Properties"]
```

to get a perspective what kind of properties one can search for, in case of `Gamma`  it works like e.g.

```
MathematicalFunctionData["Gamma", "AlternativeRepresentations"]
```

or even more informative

```
MathematicalFunctionData["Gamma", "NamedIdentities"][[19 ;; 23]] //  
TraditionalForm
```

[image]

A kind of convenient browser of mathematical properties one can get evaluating

```
Manipulate[ Entity["MathematicalFunction", "Gamma"][z],
            {z, Entity["MathematicalFunction", "Gamma"]["Properties"]}]
```

Comment: Thanks, getting information in the traditional form can make searching for my formula easier.

Comment: @janhardo You are welcome!  You have also link to Wolfram functions `MathematicalFunctionData["Gamma", "WolframFunctionsSiteLink"]`. Nontheless I find the browser with `Manipulate` a more convenient way of exploiting  built-in mathematical data .

Answer (score 7):

Use `Entity["MathematicalFunction", "Gamma"]`

```
(prodRep = #[z] & /@
     Most[Entity["MathematicalFunction", "Gamma"][
       "ProductRepresentations"]]) // Column[#, Frame -> All] & //
 TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Also look at `Entity["MathematicalFunction", "Gamma"]["Properties"]`

Comment: Thanks, Can also use this to perform a targeted search and put the result in a box in the desired output..handy